# Замена слайдера на форму

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Вот [демо](http://www.ellipsetours.com/Demos/storage/), вот [код](https://github.com/axshon/HTML-5-Ellipse-Tours/tree/master/demos/storage).
Как заменить слайдер на форму с полями ввода?

```js
    /// Copyright 2011, Ian Gilman
    /// Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
    ///
    /// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js" />
    /// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    /// <reference path="Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" />
    /// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" />
    
    // ----------
    $(document).ready(function () {
      Main.init();
    });
    
    // ----------
    window.Main = {
      nextBoxIndex: 0, 
      offset: 0,
      $slider: null,
      $selectedBox: null, 
      
      // ----------
      init: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        if (!Modernizr.localstorage) {
          alert("This browser does not support local storage.");
          return;
        }
        
        if (!Modernizr.hsla) {
          alert("This browser does not support hsl.");
          return;
        }
        
        if (!window.JSON) {
          alert("This browser does not support JSON.");
          return;
        }
        
        $("#new")
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            var $box = self.createBox();
            self.saveBox($box);
          });
    
        $("#clear")
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            self.clearAll();
          });
    
        $(window)
          .bind("storage", function() {
            setTimeout(function() { // this slight delay is necessary on IE
              self.loadAll();
            }, 1);
          });
    
        this.initDialog();
        this.loadAll();
      }, 
      
      // ----------
      initDialog: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        this.$slider = $("#hue")
          .slider({
            min: 0, 
            max: 360, 
            slide: function(event, ui) {
              self.setHue(self.$selectedBox, ui.value);
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
              self.setHue(self.$selectedBox, ui.value);
              self.saveBox(self.$selectedBox);
            }
          });
      },
      
      // ----------
      loadAll: function() {
        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
          var key = localStorage.key(i);
          if (key.indexOf("box-") !== 0)
            continue;
            
          var data = localStorage[key];
          var box = JSON.parse(data);
          var id = "#" + key;
          ids.push(id);
          
          var $box = $(id);
          if (!$box.length)
            $box = this.createBox(key);
    
          $box
            .css({
              left: box.left, 
              top: box.top
            }); 
            
          this.setHue($box, box.hue);
        }
        
        var found = ids.join(", ");
        $(".box").not(found).remove();
      },
      
      // ----------  
      clearAll: function() {
        $(".box").remove();
        localStorage.clear();
      },
      
      // ----------
      createBox: function(key) {
        var self = this;
        
        var index;
        if (key) {
          var parts = key.split("-");
          index = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
          this.nextBoxIndex = Math.max(index, this.nextBoxIndex) + 1;
        } else {
          index = this.nextBoxIndex;
          key = "box-" + index;
          this.nextBoxIndex++;
          this.offset += 20;
        }
        
        var html = "<div class='box box-shadow box-round'>"
          + "Drag me<br>"
          + "or <button class='change-color'>change color</button><br>"
          + "or <button class='remove'>remove</button>"
          + "</div>";
        
        var $box = $(html)
          .attr("id", key)
          .css({
            left: this.offset, 
            top: this.offset, 
            "z-index": index
          })
          .appendTo("body")
          .draggable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
              self.saveBox($box);
            }
          });
          
        this.setHue($box, this.offset);
    
        $box.find(".change-color")
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            self.startDialogFor($box);
          });
          
        $box.find(".remove")
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            self.removeBox($box);
          });
          
        return $box;
      },
      
      // ----------
      saveBox: function($box) {
        var position = $box.position();
        localStorage[$box.attr("id")] = JSON.stringify({
          left: position.left, 
          top: position.top,
          hue: $box.data("hue")
        });
      }, 
      
      // ----------
      removeBox: function($box) {
        $box.remove();
        localStorage.removeItem($box.attr("id"));
      },
    
      // ----------
      startDialogFor: function($box) {
        var $dialog = $("#dialog")
          .dialog({
            resizable: false
          });
          
        var $colorButton = $box.find(".change-color")
        var buttonPosition = $colorButton.offset(); 
        $dialog.dialog("option", "position", [
          buttonPosition.left + (($colorButton.outerWidth() - $dialog.outerWidth()) / 2), 
          buttonPosition.top + ($colorButton.outerHeight() * 1.5)
        ]);
    
        this.$selectedBox = $box;
        this.$slider.slider("value", this.$selectedBox.data("hue")); 
      },
      
      // ----------
      setHue: function($box, hue) {
        $box.data("hue", hue);
        $box.css({
          "background-color": "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 75%)"
        });
      }
    };
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Local Storage</title>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link     href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.21/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="dialog" title="Choose Hue">
        <div id="hue"></div>
      </div>
      <button id="new">New</button>
      <button id="clear">Clear</button>
      <aside id="info">
        <p>This is a demo of the HTML5 <a href="http://www.joelennon.ie/2011/02/11/basics-of-html5-localstorage/"     target="_blank">localStorage API</a> (with a little <a href="http://jqueryui.com/" target="_blank">jQuery UI</a> thrown in for good measure).</p>
        <p>Create some boxes, move them around, change their colors, then refresh the page to see that everything is remembered. Open this page in a second window and see that both windows stay in sync.</p>
    <p>Written by <a href="http://iangilman.com/" target="_blank">Ian Gilman</a> as part of a <a href="../index.html">series of demos</a> for the book <a href="http://www.manning.com/jackson/" target="_blank">HTML5 for .NET Developers</a>, co-authored by <a href="https://twitter.com/axshon" target="_blank">Jim Jackson II</a>; code <a href="https://github.com/axshon/HTML-5-Ellipse-Tours/blob/master/demos/storage/Scripts/main.js" target="_blank">available on Github</a>.</p>
      </aside>
      <script src="Scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Процитируйте свой код сюда, в SO.

Comment: @mix, у меня почему-то при нажатии на "Выполнить код" появляется алерт о том, что браузер не поддерживает Local Storage, но я в Хроме смотрю, и в консоли main.js  и др. файлы не загружены.
(http://s017.radikal.ru/i412/1603/44/73a090a37e44.png)
(http://s015.radikal.ru/i332/1603/ba/3c6c94af434e.png)